# When does my McAfee Anti-Virus start: On installation or on activation?

Tags: anti-virus

I recently purchase McAfee Anti-Virus online but I haven't activated it because my previous antivirus software has few more days left.

Not sure if anyone knows, but in McAfee Anti-Virus when does the countdown timer starts, does it start once you activate the software or it will start when you start installing it on your device?

Comment: I hope you didn't install the new one yet, until after you've uninstalled the old one. They fight. Time probably starts when you see the money's gone from your bank account/paypal etc. They don't care when you actually press the go button..

Comment: Nope I haven't installed it yet and even activated it, too afraid that it will start its timer as soon as it got activated.

Comment: This information is going to be in your purchase information and we cannot tell you that. AV is a subscription more than a license, and in my experience most go from the time of purchase rather than the time of install.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm it, I was able to extend my old license using my new license so I didn’t waste a day with the new and old antivirus software that I have.

Not sure if its same to other product but the AV I am using is Mcafee Total Protection. Hopefully this information is useful to other users out there.